# Difference between setVideoFrameRate and setCaptureRate / MediaRecorder start failed: -19?

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Q1. Can I use both setVideoFrameRate and setCaptureRate at the sametime? Can anyone explain the difference and when to use which of the two?

Q2. Is the below code flow correct? I get **MediaRecorder start failed: -19** error with *Nexus 7 (2013) Android 4.3* **front camera**. With back camera, the same code works perfectly fine without any error. Can anyone correct the below code and why it is working for back and not for front camera?

```
public void saveVideo(int resX, int resY, int bitRate, int fps, Camera camera){

        File tempFile = null;
        MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
        try{                                    

            tempFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraApp/"+"_"+resX+"x"+resY+"_"+bitRate+"_"+fps+".mp4");                  

            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(); 
            camera.unlock();            
            mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);                              
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);                       
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);                       
            mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(resX, resY);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(fps);   
            //mediaRecorder.setCaptureRate(fps);
            mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(bitRate);         
            mediaRecorder.setOnErrorListener(new MediaRecorder.OnErrorListener()
            {

                @Override
                public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                    Log.i("MainActivity", "MediaRecorder Error");
                }

            });

            mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(tempFile.toString());
            mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
            mediaRecorder.prepare();                
            mediaRecorder.start();

            Thread.sleep(5000); // Recording for 1 second
        }
        catch (InterruptedException interrptedException ) {

        }
        catch ( IOException ioException){

        }
        catch(IllegalStateException illegalState){

        }

        if (mediaRecorder != null) {    

            try {
                mediaRecorder.stop();
            }
            catch (IllegalStateException illegal){

            }
            mediaRecorder.reset();   // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null; 

        }
            camera.lock();


}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setCaptureRate` is used in time lapse case. `setVideoFrameRate` is used in normal record case.

If `setCaptureRate` fails, maybe your device doesn't support time lapse mode.